# Starting format for text file to be converted to other formats

Tags: type-conversion, latex, doc, file-conversion

I need to write a document using images, texts, hyperlinks... And then convert it to PDF and DOC (but in the future it can be converted to more file formats).
What's the best "starting format" for this document?

Answer (score 0):

Doc or Docx might be the best file format for creating the document containing images, texts, hyperlinks, and many more elements. Once created, it's easy to convert files in .doc/.docx format into other file format, such as Image, PDF, HTML, by using OpenXML or even commercial library like Spire.Doc.